# Cordova - how to upload captured image by Camera.getPicture to server

Tags: javascript, java, json, api, cordova

I have following code, which takes picture and save image into DCIM/Camera/filename/ on Android.My question is how to upload this file onto server like ocr.space, by using **formData**.My code says **No file uploaded or URL provided**, which means im not giving file, but only path to location.Ive tried this in windows too with no success.So whats the correct way to upload file from local path?When i use URL like form.append("url", url ) instead of local path, its working properly.**I would like to say that im not able to use file input** , because its cant be filled dynamiccaly for security reasons so user must choose file and i want to send it automatically.

```
function capturePhoto() {
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50 });
}

function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData) {                
    temppath = imageData;


var form = new FormData();

form.append("apikey", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
form.append("language", "Czech");
form.append("isOverlayRequired", "true");
form.append("file", temppath );



var settings = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "https://api.ocr.space/parse/image",
  "method": "POST",
  "headers": {
    "cache-control": "no-cache",
    "postman-token": "01872f0e-7d67-3210-9929-13696ed792c7"
  },
  "processData": false,
  "contentType": false,
  "mimeType": "multipart/form-data",
  "data": form
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
}); 


}

function onFail(message) {
    alert('Failed to load picture because: ' + message);
}
```

Comment: Cordova has a nice [file transfer library](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer). Why are you rolling your own version?  I've used this library and it's solid.

Comment: I know file transfer but this is ready script of ocr.space API and i dont know if it will be working by file transfer to get their results can you give me some specific code for that containing language api key overlay true and file? thanks

Comment: The problem is this not working even on pc because as i said when i make variable with file path its not appending whole file but only path to my disk which of  is of course  insufficient.ive tried to make file object new image() etc. and base64 string both with no success.only way how it works is from input type = file which as i said cannot use..